# Javascript toggle image border works in Firefox but not IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, compatibility

My code below works in Firefox to toggle a border on an image,but does not work in IE. Any ideas why ? In IE, the first click will add the border, but the second click will not remove the border again.

Thanks,
Leslie

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function(){

    for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++){
        document.images[i].onclick=function(){
        if(this.style.border == '2px solid red')
        {
            this.style.border='';
        }
        else this.style.border='2px solid red';
        }
    }

}

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="Cat.jpg" width="250"/>
        <img src="Dog.jpg" width="250"/>
        <img src="Fish.jpg" width="250"/>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strangely enough, I had the reverse problem when I was trying to do something with the `color` property. IE returned the `#800000` I had set it to, but Firefox returned `rgb(128,0,0)` instead. Sometimes I wish browsers would spit out what they've been given, and leave the computed value for `getComputedStyle()`, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `if(this.style.border == '2px solid red')`, and it's rigth for FF but 
IE returns `red 2px solid` so if condition doesn't match with IE. You may try this

```
window.onload=function(){
for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++)
{
    document.images[i].onclick=function(){
        if(this.style.borderColor == 'red' && this.style.borderStyle=='solid' && this.style.borderWidth=='2px')
        {
            this.style.border='none';
        } 
        else this.style.border='2px solid red';
      }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/RK2Gb/5/)

**Alternative:** [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/RK2Gb/4/) **or** [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/RK2Gb/7/) (Better when you've other classes).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/BPPvv/1/

Notice the difference that is returned. This is likely just an IE issue - you should use class assignments instead of string compares

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++)
       {
        alert(this.style.border);
        document.images[i].onclick=function(){
        if(this.style.border == '2px solid red')
         {
            this.style.border='';
         }
        else 
         { // missed this bracket AND shorthand for borders should be
         this.style.border='2px solid red';
         }
       }

    }​
```

Comment: It doesn't matter because else statement is on a single line.

Comment: amended with the real issue - neat code is always pleasant regardless.

Comment: looks like an xbrowser issue. See Fiddle in answer